# Techniques to avoid changing CSS selectors?

Tags: css, selenium, web-scraping

The thing is that I am working on a web scraping project to the edreams website, and the selector that refers to the next button changes continuously. A few days ago it was:

```
#search_results_table > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.d7a0553560 > div.b727170def > nav > div > div.f32a99c8d1.f78c3700d2 > button > span > svg
```

And now it is:

```
#search_results_table > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.d7a0553560 > div.a826ba81c4.fa71cba65b.fa2f36ad22.afd256fc79.d08f526e0d.ed11e24d01.ef9845d4b3.b727170def > nav > div > div.f32a99c8d1.f78c3700d2 > button
```

This is because a part of my code is:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#search_results_table > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.d7a0553560 > div.b727170def > nav > div > div.f32a99c8d1.f78c3700d2 > button > span > svg').click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

So, what happens is that every time I run the code that makes the web scraping to obtain the data, there are execution errors due to the change of the css selectors.

Any technique that you know can be useful?

Comment: How do **you** know that's the thing that needs clicking at that point?

Comment: Please share ALL your Selenium code, especially the page(s) you want to scroll. I saw no element you mentioned on the main page there

Comment: Well that Xpath refers to the button to go to the next page.

Comment: That's not an XPath. If you used an XPath you could look for "Next Page" or whatever the button says on it.